# Skipping cache generation, cache already exists for key

Tags: caching, continuous-integration, package.json, circleci

Using **CircleCI** - `version: 2.1` - for continuous deployment where caching installed dependencies. Based on [`save_cache`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#save_cache) documentation:

> Generates and stores a cache of a file or directory of files such as dependencies or source code in our object storage. Later jobs can restore this cache.

**Current scenario:**

See the *simplified* caching step below in *.circleci/config.yml* file:

```
steps:
  - node/with-cache:
      steps:
        - checkout
        - run: npm install
        - save_cache:
            key: dependencies
            paths: node_modules
```

The problem is coming once adding new package to the project thus **package.json** file is changing. In the same time **CircleCI** shows the message for **Saving Cache** step:

> Skipping cache generation, cache already exists for key: dependencies
> Found one created at 2020-05-23 19:29:29 +0000 UTC

Then once restoring the cache obviously does not find the newly added package in the build step:

> ./src/index.tsx
> Cannot find module: '*package-name*'. Make sure this package is installed.

**Questions:**

Is there any way to check **package.json** changes in the pipeline? Ideally I would install the dependencies only in those cases, so the cache can be purged and updated.

Maybe I did not see something in the documentation. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the cache key you used is "dependencies", a plain string. This key never changes, so you will always use the same exact cache.

You need to use a cache key that changes, preferably based on `package.lock`. Please read the section of cache keys in the CircleCI Docs for more information: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#using-keys-and-templates

Comment: Based on the documentation what you linked I have applied `dependencies-{{ checksum "package-lock.json" }}` for the `key` in `save_cache` and `restore_cache` cases which did the trick, thanks for helping!